# Set-ADUser : The name reference is invalid

Tags: powershell

When trying to run below Powershell command getting error  :

```
Set-ADUser -Identity suser -Add @{msExchDelegateListLink='CN=Customer Care,OU=Onlinetenent.onmicrosoft.com,OU=Microsoft Exchange Hosted Organizations,DC=NMPR19A04,DC=PROD,DC=OUTLOOK,DC=COM'}

Set-ADUser : The name reference is invalid
At line:3 char:77
+ ... rt.com'}  | Set-ADUser -Add @{msExchDelegateListLink='CN=Customer Car ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (CN=user test...=proddom,DC=net:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8373,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

Comment: Could you add all of your code/more of your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This article suggests the DN of the user you are referencing is incorrect:
https://c7solutions.com/category/msexchdelegatelistlink

Looking at the DN in your sample, assuming you copied and pasted, you may have misspelled "tenant" in `OU=Onlinetenent.onmicrosoft.com,`